# Image not showing in first time objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on objective c.i am facing issue in imageview.Image is not showing in first time, when we go to next view controller and back to previous controller then image is showing.whts going wrong please suggest me.

Here is the code

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",UserDetail[@"profilePic"]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            profileImage.image = image;
            firstLetterlabel.hidden = true;
        });
    });
```

Comment: please show the relevant code!

Comment: It's because of line 2 in your the second file of your project (sorted by alphabetical order). Clearly, we don't know without code. Is it an async problem? An issue with main thread?

Comment: UIImageView  *profileImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, topbarView.frame.size.height-45, 35, 35)];
    profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    profileImage.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"aeaeae"] CGColor];
     profileImage.image = nil;
    [topbarView addSubview:profileImage];

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code before you set Image to imageview

```
Yourimageview.clipsToBounds = true;
[Yourimageview layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Thanks Mitul let me try